# Flat surface sculpts along length, not evenly

Tags: sculpting

So I have run into this issue when learning to create a base mesh of a head. In the following picture I have created a basic nose.

[image: Basic Nose]

I enter sculpt mode and press ctrl + r to remesh the object, and smooth it out a bit

[image: Remeshed Nose]

Here is a view from the bottom up where I try to start the nostrils.

[image]

Why is the draw brush drawing ovals instead of circles?

First time poster here. If there is any additional information I can provide I would be happy to.

Answer (score 1):

try appllying scale by hitting ctrl-A apply scale  blender works weird when scale of object is not 1